# Is there a more shorter, more elegant way of writing this?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello all and thank you for your time, the code below works perfectly but I'm using it in thousands of other cells and was wondering if there is an equivalent shorter version of this?

```
Worksheets("Monthly").Range("B7").Value = "Series 2"

Worksheets("Monthly").Range("C7").Value = _
Worksheets("Approved Series 2").Range("U3").Value

Worksheets("Monthly").Range("D7").Value = _
Worksheets("Approved Series 2").Range("U4").Value

Worksheets("Monthly").Range("E7").Value = _
Worksheets("Approved Series 2").Range("U6").Value

Worksheets("Monthly").Range("F7").Value = _
Worksheets("Approved Series 2").Range("U7").Value
```

Comment: You could use a `With` block and / or set the sheets to variables. This would mean you only use the sheet name once which is less prone to human errors such as typos/easier to debug and probably shorter to type

Comment: With thousand of other cells, you better start looking to get rid of the direct cell references. (What if a row is inserted in your "Approved Series 2" worksheet?

Comment: Thank you for the answers, unfortunatly I'm a beginner in vba and don't really know where to start with ```With``` and so on Tom, is there a little sample you can write for me?

Comment: That is a GOOD point EvR, I did not think of that, so what else would I use if I eliminate direct cell reference? I just want to copy a cell from a sheet into a cell on another sheet.

Comment: Have a look at Defined Names and Tables in Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Tom's comment, you could do something like this:

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Monthly")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Approved Series 2")

sht1.Range("C7") = sht2.Range("U3")
```

and so on.  If it is always the same action repeated it would be possible to use a loop so you don't have to write the statement out lots of times.

Comment: Thank you and Tom, this is way better.

Comment: You could also skip the variable name and use the sheets `CodeName` This is the name assigned to a sheet in the editor window so `Sheets("Sheet1")` can usually be referenced in `VBA` as `Sheet1`

Comment: @Tom Worth to mention that while this is true as long as nobody changed the tab names, it is technically possible that in one workbook `Sheet1` and `Sheets("Sheet1")` can be 2 completely different sheets. It is essential to know that these 2 names are not related at all. Actually there exist 2 different (non-related) naming systems: The VBA CodeName (that can be edited in the VBA Editor's properties window) and the tab name of the sheet.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for the addition - I was just giving a basic example. These can all change however, I prefer to refer to sheet objects with a reference that is the most difficult for the end user to change

Answer (score 3):

You could shorten it by writing a procedure:

```
Private Sub CopyValue(Destination As String, Source As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Monthly").Range(Destination).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Approved Series 2").Range(Source).Value
End Sub
```

So you can use it like this …

```
CopyValue "C7", "U3"
CopyValue "D7", "U4"
CopyValue "E7", "U6"
CopyValue "F7", "U7"
```